# compute and plot arithmetic functions in C++ for large integer?

Tags: c++, plot, biginteger

How can I write a C++ code and which library I can use to **compute** and **plot** the sum of divisors or some similar arithmetic functions for large integers, for example integers bigger than 10^100 000.

For example the code I wrote in Mathematica:

```
g[n_] := Product[Prime[i], {i, 1, PrimePi[n]}];


k[999990]=g[237179]*g[661]*267064515689275851355624017992790*223092870*30030*44100*30*1296*512;

k[999991]=g[237173]*g[661]*23768741896345550770650537601358310*200560490130*30030*44100*30*7776*256;

k[999992]=g[237179]*g[661]*3217644767340672907899084554130*6469693230*30030*44100*30*7776*256;

k[999993]=g[237173]*g[673]*267064515689275851355624017992790*6469693230*30030*44100*900*1296*256;

k[999994]=g[237163]*g[677]*23768741896345550770650537601358310*200560490130*30030*44100*30*7776*256;

k[999995]=g[237179]*g[659]*23768741896345550770650537601358310*6469693230*30030*44100*30*1296*256;

ds[n_] := DivisorSigma[1, n];  %sum of divisors

f1[n_] := EulerPhi[n];         %number of coprimes less than n

d[n_] := DivisorSigma[0, n];   %number of divisors 

f[n_] := DivisorSigma[1, n]/(n*Log[n]]);

sp[n_] := Sum[1/Prime[i], {i, 1, n}];
```

I use **Mathematica 8** to compute and plot them, but it takes too long time such as one day or more.
Is there any code in C++ to compute and sum of divisors for large numbers very fast.

I use windows 7 64 bit. I have downloaded **Dev C++, codeblocks, and Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition**. I asked someone and he told me to use GMP(The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library). but I don't know how to use it as well.!

Actually I need the plots like the following(lines connecting points) not smooth graphs like sin or cos.

[the sample graph type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZZEF.png)

thanks

Comment: with GMP you can create `mpz_class` (for multiple precision integer) with a constructor taking an std::string. Usual operators are overridden for you to perform arithmetic operations.

Comment: @Bernoit, I have code::block and devc++.  How can I use gmplib in this compilers. I downloaded gmp-5.0.1.tar, gmp-4.3.1-1ext, gmp-4.3.1-2ext. but now i dont know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use GMP library http://gmplib.org/ 
for all these kind of heavy computation. It uses big int to store such big values